# If $Hom(M,N) = 0$ then the ideal $I + J =\{a + b : a \in I,b \in J\}$ coincides with the ring R.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $I$ and $J$ be ideals in a PID $R$. Suppose $M = R/I $ and $N = R/J.$
Show that if $Hom(M,N) = 0$ then the ideal
$$I + J = \{a + b : a \in I,b \in J\}$$
coincides with the ring R.

I only can prove $I+J$ is an ideal, but I don't know how to use the assumption that $Hom(M,N)=0$.

Help me, thank you so much!

Comment: Which category are you taking $\operatorname{Hom}(M,N)$ -- Rings or $R$-modules?  (certainly not abelian groups I hope)

Comment: I don't think this is right. Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $I=2\mathbb{Z}$, and $J=\{0\}$. Then $\mathrm{Hom}(M,N) = \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}) = \{0\}$, but $I+J = 2\mathbb{Z}\neq \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $\mathrm{Hom}(M,N)$ is taken in the category of $R$-modules.

The assertion is incorrect as stated: take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, certainly a PID (in fact, one might argue *the* PID). Let $I=2\mathbb{Z}$, $J=(0)$. Then $M=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $N=\mathbb{Z}$. There are no nonzero group homomorphisms from $M$ to $N$, let alone ring or module homomorphisms. But $I+J = 2\mathbb{Z}\neq\mathbb{Z}$.

However, *if* we also assume that $J$ is nonzero, then the assertion holds.

Let $I=(a)$, $J=(b)$, and $I+J=(c)$. Consider $R/(I+J) = R/(c)$. Write $a=cx$, $b=cy$. Define a function $f\colon M\to N$ by $f(r+I) = ry+J$.

I claim that this is well defined. If $r+I=s+I$, then $r-s\in I$, hence $r-s=at$ for some $t\in R$. Then $ry-sy = (r-s)y = aty = csty = st(cy) = stb\in J$. Thus, $ry+J=sy+J$, so $f$ is well defined.

Moreover, $f$ is a module homomorphism: $f((r+I)+(s+I)) = f((r+s)+I = (r+s)y+J = (ry+sy)+ J = (ry + J) + (sy+J) = f(r+I) + f(s+J)$.

And given $t\in R$, $f(t(r+I)) = f(tr+I) = try+J = t(ry+J) = tf(r+I)$.

Since $f\in\mathrm{Hom}(M,N)$, it follows that $f$ is the zero map.  But in particular, this means that $f(1+I) = y+J = J$. That is, $y\in J$, so $y$ is a multiple of $b$; hence $y=bt$ for some $t$. Since $b=cy$, we get that $y=bt=cyt$. Thus, either $y=0$, or else $ct=1$.

If $y=0$, that means that $b=cy = 0$, so $J=(0)$, which we explicitly prohibited. Thus, we must have $ct=1$, hence $c$ is a unit. But if $c$ is a unit, then $I+J = (c) = (1) = R$, as desired.